# My UIPageViewController keeps crashing

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, uipageviewcontroller, crash

I have spent hours trying to debug this using the instruments and StackOverFlow, but I haven't found a solution. My UIPageViewController keeps crashing, and I really think it's because the CPU is reaching 100% and the memory can reach high levels. However, I couldn't find any variables or any strong references that would prevent previous undisplayed View Controllers from deallocating. I think it's a memory issue in the PageViewController, but I am not a 100% sure. I am pretty new to Swift, and I really am having a hard time trying to debut this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for my `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.

```
import UIKit

class HarishIntroduction: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.pageViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    weak var initialViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishIntroduction") as? HarishIntroduction
    let viewController = NSArray(object: initialViewController!)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewController as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishIntroduction) {
        return nil
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishPlaces) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishIntroduction") as? HarishIntroduction
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(WyomingSeminary) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPlaces") as? HarishPlaces
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(AppleTree) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WyomingSeminary") as? WyomingSeminary
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(KearneyHighSchool) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppleTree") as? AppleTree
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(MosconeCenter) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KearneyHighSchool") as? KearneyHighSchool
        return correctViewController
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishIntroduction) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPlaces") as? HarishPlaces
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishPlaces) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WyomingSeminary") as? WyomingSeminary
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(WyomingSeminary) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppleTree") as? AppleTree
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(AppleTree) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KearneyHighSchool") as? KearneyHighSchool
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(KearneyHighSchool) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MosconeCenter") as? MosconeCenter
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(MosconeCenter) {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The initial view controller is the "HarishIntroduction."

Comment: At what point is it crashing?? Did you try adding any symbolic breakpoints?

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't get a crash message at all. Actually, it is strange the whole system crashes and reboots and all I get in the console is a message that says that the XPC connection has been interrupted and basically it lost connection to the simulator.

Comment: @satheeshwaran See comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not the right way, you are trying to instantiate a UIPageViewController with an initial view controller as the view controller which is in turn the parent of the UIPageViewController.

I am doing this on a separate class and all works well, I created only two view controller though in the page controller hierarchy. You can add more, no issues with that.

And there is no need for doing a dispatch_async on main_queue on viewDidLoad, because you are already in the main_queue with viewDidLoad, take away that code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var harishStoryboard:UIStoryboard!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.harishStoryboard = self.storyboard

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.pageViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    let initialViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishIntroduction") as! HarishIntroduction
    let viewController = NSArray(object: initialViewController)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewController as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishIntroduction) {
        return nil
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishPlaces) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishIntroduction") as? HarishIntroduction
        return correctViewController
    }
    /*if viewController.isKindOfClass(WyomingSeminary) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPlaces") as? HarishPlaces
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(AppleTree) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WyomingSeminary") as? WyomingSeminary
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(KearneyHighSchool) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppleTree") as? AppleTree
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(MosconeCenter) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KearneyHighSchool") as? KearneyHighSchool
        return correctViewController
    }*/
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishIntroduction) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HarishPlaces") as? HarishPlaces
        return correctViewController
    }
    /*if viewController.isKindOfClass(HarishPlaces) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WyomingSeminary") as? WyomingSeminary
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(WyomingSeminary) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppleTree") as? AppleTree
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(AppleTree) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KearneyHighSchool") as? KearneyHighSchool
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(KearneyHighSchool) {
        let correctViewController = harishStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MosconeCenter") as? MosconeCenter
        return correctViewController
    }
    if viewController.isKindOfClass(MosconeCenter) {
        return nil
    }*/
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

The code above works well for me, if needed I can upload the project for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I tried out the code above, and the app wouldn't crash. However, whenever I swiped the UIPageViewController was unresponsive, and it wouldn't load any of the other views. I looked at the code for any possible spelling errors, but I found none. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is your initial view controller? Kindly update the current code in your question.

Comment: Ok, I will do it one minute.

Comment: I added it to my question, the Initial View Controller is "HarishIntroduction."

Comment: yes that is wrong, add another view controller lets call it PageViewContainerController that will have all the code in the HarishIntroduction view controller and HarishIntroduction contrller should be the initial view controller in it.

Comment: The point is you are trying to add a type of self as the initial view controller which is holding the page view controller, you should do all that business in another class.

Comment: Ok, so I make another view controller, and then I just copy and paste the code from the HarishIntroduction View Controller into that one? However, what should I put in the "HarishIntroduction" view controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99139/discussion-between-harish-and-satheeshwaran).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I think I finally got it working. Everything is working as expected, and it is running smoothly without any crashes. The CPU is maintaining normal levels, but the memory is reaching around 90-100 MB. Is that normal? I tested it out in the simulator, since I don't have access to an iPhone right now. What do you think would be around a normal memory level for a UIPageViewController? I really have to thank you so much because I have been working on this nonstop for days, and now it is finally working. Thanks :).

Comment: You are welcome, don't worry about the memory for now, check for leaks or dead allocations. My though 90-100 mb is normal. I currently work on a tab bar app and it holds around 130+mb on the sim.

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks a lot. Page View Controller is now working great and lag free without any crashes. I will check for any leaks using the Instruments in Xcode! Thanks!